# Fastly CDN not refresh custom page

Tags: magento-2.1, cache, cdn, caching

We have Fastly CDN configured in Website, and we have a custom page where we are displaying product listing. When admin makes changes in the product, it's reflecting correctly in front-end product details page but not in product listing page.

This listing page is custom page not default Magento category or product listing page.

So is there any configuration in Fastly CDN or in Magento 2 to refresh cache automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can flush fastly via cli using

```
curl -X POST \ 
https://api.fastly.com/service/{key}/purge_all \ 
-H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \ 
-H 'Fastly-Key: XXXXXX' \ 
-H 'Postman-Token: XXXXXX'
```

Or you can purge under `System->cache management`